# Infragistics context menu not closing

Tags: .net, vb.net, contextmenu, infragistics

In my application i use Infragistics controls. Sometimes everything works perfectly, but sometimes context menu is not closing if clicked anywhere else.
Example:
1) Right click on item
2) Click somewhere outside context menu
3) Context menu should close, but sometimes it stays open, until you click an item inside it.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Some code, how contextual menu is created and added to grid.

```
Dim contextualMenu As PopupMenuTool = New PopupMenuTool(key)
contextualMenu.DropDownArrowStyle = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.DropDownArrowStyle.SegmentedStateButton
AddHandler contextualMenu.BeforeToolDropdown, AddressOf Me.contextualMenu_BeforeToolDropdown

Dim deleteItem As ButtonTool = New ButtonTool("delete")
deleteItem.SharedProps.AppearancesSmall.Appearance.Image = ImagesResources.Delete
deleteItem.SharedProps.Caption = Captions.Delete
AddHandler deleteItem.ToolClick, AddressOf Me.DeleteClick

Dim closeItem As ButtonTool = New ButtonTool("close")
closeItem.SharedProps.AppearancesSmall.Appearance.Image = ImagesResources.Close
closeItem.SharedProps.Caption = Captions.Close
AddHandler closeItem.ToolClick, AddressOf Me.CloseClick

Me.BaseToolbarsManager.Tools.Add(contextualMenu)
Me.BaseToolbarsManager.Tools.Add(closeItem)
Me.BaseToolbarsManager.Tools.Add(deleteItem)

contextualMenu.Tools.AddTool(deleteItem.Key)
contextualMenu.Tools.AddTool(closeItem.Key)

Me.SetcontextualMenu(Me.grid, key)
```

Comment: Not without seeing the code to it.

Comment: I added code. Still having that problem.

Comment: I tried hiding all `PopupMenuTool` objects on cell click. Nothing happens, because my context menu visibility property is `false` - it is already hidden, but stuck and visible.

Comment: Very odd. On the cell click, try testing the visibility of contextualmenu. On the rare occasions that it might be visible, make it invisible. Another thing to try is on the cell click, always make it visible and immediately make it invisible.

Comment: Also, if you setup your menu through the properties window, does the behavior act any different?

Comment: Making it visible and invisible does not help. If i set up through properties window, behavior is the same.

Comment: Hmmm. Since the visible/invisible may be swallowed within the cell click call, put a MyDoEvents call after the visible and after the invisible call. I included the function in an answer below so you can copy and paste to try it.

Comment: Ok... the next thing I would suggest to try would be to delete the grid context menu or set to nothing in the cell click event, and then re-create it. A little drastic perhaps, but it is a different approach.

Comment: You can always try a standard context menu instead of using Infragistics to see if the same behavior occurs. BTW, what version of Infragistics are you using?

Comment: I am using Infragistics 10.3

Comment: That is 5 years old. You can download version 15.1 on a demo basis for 30 days. I would make a copy of your project first and then run the Version Utility to upgrade it to 15.1 and see if that fixes it. They have done a lot of bug fixes since 2010.

Comment: I tried with simple contextMenu and it works perfectly. Now i have 2 options: migrate to newer infragistics version, or modify my code to use standard context menu instead of infragistics one.

Comment: You can do a lot more with infragistics. Just because you can, may not mean that you should, though there are a lot of other controls and features that I have found to be really, really handy. You might try the demo of the new version to see if it is worth it to you, and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment above, give this function call a try after the visible and invisible call:

```
Private Sub MyDoEvents()
    Dim CurrMsg         As MSG

    'The following loop extract all messages from the queue and dispatch them
    'to the appropriate window.
    Do While PeekMessage(CurrMsg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) <> 0
        TranslateMessage CurrMsg
        DispatchMessage CurrMsg
    Loop
End Sub
```

This will make sure the code gets executed within the cell click event.

Comment: Sorry, this does not help. But i noticed one interesting fact: setting visibility to false of PopupMenuTool does not hide it, but if i loop through its child elements and hide them, the become hidden, but i still can see PopupMenuTool which now is empty

Comment: I tried adding AfterToolDeactivate event to PopupMenuTool, but breakpoint never hits. It works only if i add AfterToolDeactivate event to its child elements. But still, hiding it does not work.

Comment: Using newer version of Infragistics is not an option for me, so i recreated all context menus without infragistics and now it works perfectly.